# What is !0 in C?

Tags: c, boolean

I know that in C, for if statements and comparisons FALSE = 0 and anything else equals true.

Hence,

```
int j = 40
int k = !j

k == 0 // this is true
```

My question handles the opposite. What does !0 become? 1?

```
int l = 0
int m = !l

m == ? // what is m?
```

Comment: @Josh K: Perfect advice.  I wish everyone would try it first, and then ask about the results they *actually* got.

Comment: @Josh K: Because it may well vary by compiler / standard / day of the week (if it's not defined behavior, for example, although obviously it is in this case), so seeing a single result value may not accurately reflect what it will be on any other given setup.

Comment: Not possible on my current equipment. I'm having trouble getting my C compiler to work -- which is its own question, I suppose. :P

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: "which is its own question"  Precisely.  Please don't ask random hypotheticals because there's no "answer".  Just opinions.

Comment: @S.Lott: There are no "opinions" here.  The behavior is spelled out clearly in the standard.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: "The behavior is spelled out clearly in the standard".  Except in those places where the standard says the behavior is undefined.  This appears to be a case where the standard applies.

Comment: This behavior of the `!` operator was mentioned in K&R first edition in section 2.6 on page 38: "The unary negation operator `!` converts a non-zero or true operand into 0, and a zero of false operand into 1."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Boolean/logical operators in C are required to yield either 0 or 1.

From section 6.5.3.3/5 of the ISO C99 standard:

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0.

In fact, `!!x` is a common idiom for forcing a value to be either 0 or 1 (I personally prefer `x != 0`, though).

Also see [Q9.2 from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/bool/bool2.html).

Comment: Good call. Looks like more of us need to actually read the damn ISO Standard.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the standard, but code that uses `!!` needs to head straight to the garbage can.

Comment: Of course not a lot of C compilers feel particularly compelled to follow the ISO standard. GCC probably, but with anyone else its a crapshoot.

Comment: Please link to the ISO standard, so that we too can look it up sometimes.

Comment: GCC, ICC, clang, the IBM and HP compiler tools all make a good faith effort to follow the standard.  I'm sure I'm forgetting some others.  MSVC is the only compiler I've encountered that doesn't at least *try* to follow the standard.

Comment: @BiGYaN: AFAIK the C standard must be purchased, and I am not aware of a legitimate, free version that I could link to.  Also see http://c-faq.com/ansi/avail.html

Comment: Curious: Is this true in C89?

Comment: @mathepic: Yes, it's true for C89 as well (section 6.3.3.3).

Comment: @Billy ONeal: To my mind, saying "flagvar = !!(multibitFlag & BIT_OF_INTEREST);" is clearer than "flagvar = ((multibitFlag & BIT_OF_INTEREST) != 0);"  What is gained by the extra verbosity of the latter format?

Comment: As I recall it, `!!x` was guaranteed by K&R to have the desirable effect of flattening true and false to exactly 1 and 0. At that time the numeric result of the other logical operators was not described. A quick search of my copy of K&R first ed. got me the sentence I quoted in another comment. I have been unable to find a sentence the specified the numeric value of `(x != 0)`, and my recollection is that we knew it might very well be the numeric value of `x` in that specific case.

Comment: @supercat: What is gained is the clarity of the code. `!!` is trying to be tricky, `!= 0` explains explicitly to the reader what the code is doing. However, in that case, there's no reason for the `!!` or `!=` at all.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: `!!` is perfectly clear to an experienced C programmer, since it's the idiomatic way of flattening a value to 1 or 0.  `!= 0` is no better since it relies on knowing that the result of the `!=` operator is either 1 or 0, as opposed to the `!` operator.  In fact I'd argue that it's worse, since `!!` more clearly conveys the intent.  If you want a better alternative, I suggest `? 1 : 0`.

Comment: Or use a C99 toolchain, `#include <stdbool.h>` and cast to `bool`.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Is a cast of any numeric type to "bool" guaranteed to convert any non-zero value to 1?  Some compilers I use have a "bit" type which behaves as a one-bit integer (so assignments just use the LSB of the source operand).

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I find the "!!" format more readable, since there's less stuff to visually parse, and to my mind the concept of "nonzero" is distinct from the concept of "doesn't equal the numerical constant zero".  And there is a reason for the "!!": if multiBitFlag grows to be bigger than flagVar, the "!!" ensures the result will fit.  It's also often nicer for routines' contracts to indicate that they'll return 1 or 0, rather than just some arbitrary non-zero value or zero (though I know that e.g. strcmp etc. merely specify the sign of their results, and not the value).

Comment: @supercat: "When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1." (§6.3.1.2)

Comment: @caf and @supercat: Inexperienced C programmers sometimes think `!!` is a distinct operator (like `&&` or `||`) and get confused.  I think double negatives generally are harder to understand, and while `!=` also requires that people understand that it produces either 0 or 1, it seems simpler since it's only one operation and not two.

Answer (score 3):

§6.5.3.3/5: "The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int."

The other logical operators (e.g., `&&`, `||`) always produce either 0 or 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, it'll become 1.  That said even if that is guaranteed behavior (which I'm not sure of) I'd consider code that relied on that to be pretty awful.

You can assume that it's a true value.  I wouldn't assume anything more.

Comment: Not just generally; *always*.  Boolean operators in C are required to return either 0 or 1.

Comment: Still, it feels like a violation of having your code show intent.

Comment: Not at all. Things like `prefix="-"+!neg;` are perfectly sane C.

Comment: @R..: I'd not seen that one before.  If neg is false, it points to the null byte at the end of the string?  Cuter than having prefix be a char which is either 45 or 0, and having the display routine filter out null bytes).

Comment: Yeah, if `neg` is false then `prefix` points to an empty string. If it's true, `prefix` points to the string `"-"` (with null termination either way, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The Bang operator (!) is the logical not operator found commonly in C, C++ and C#, so

```
!0 == 1
!1 == 0
```

This is based on the language characteristic of what is interpreted to be either true or false... in more modern languages it would be like this

```
!false == true
!true == false
```

See [DeMorgan](http://wapedia.mobi/en/De_Morgan's_laws) Law concerning truth tables...

Comment: Actually, in C++, `!` takes a `bool` operand and produces a `bool` result -- though for backward compatibility, there are implicit conversions from `bool` to `int`, with `true` converting to `1` and `false` to `0`, and from other integer types to `bool`, with `0` converting to `false`, and any other value converting to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`!x` will be expand to `(x==0)` so:

- if x=0     ->  `!x` take value from `(0==0)` = TRUE  (value 1)
- if x!=0    ->  `!x` take value from `(x==0)` = FALSE (value 0)