# double negation in C : is it guaranteed to return 0/1?

Tags: c, standards

Is `!!(x)` guaranteed by the standard to return 0/1?

Note that I am **not** asking about c++, where a bool type is defined.

Comment: @DanFego: It's had well-defined behavior since C was first standardized, so the standard shouldn't matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is !0 in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661751/what-is-0-in-c)

Comment: C has a `_Bool` type and a `bool` macro in `stdbool.h`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, in C99, see  §6.5.3.3/4:

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is **0** if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to 0, **1** if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type **int**.
>   The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

So `!x` and `!!y` can only yield 0 or 1, as `int`s.

For other operators, in C99, see also [Is the "true" result of >, <, !, &&, || or == defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687403/is-the-true-result-of-or-defined)

Comment: thanks. just if you are curious why: I am using it for uni competition, where my code will run without gcc optimizations, I found using `!!x` decreasing the time my code  by ~5% then `x = ( x ? 1 : 0)`. Anyway, thanks for the quotation of the standard, it was very helpful.

Comment: How about the other C standards?

Answer (score 15):

This is a comment really, but it's too long.

I found a very bizarre document while looking for the standard to answer your question: [*The New C Standard: An Economic and Cultural Commentary.*](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.3.pdf) And they say academia is under-funded. ([Here](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/cbook1_2.pdf) is the full, 2083 page 10.5MB PDF. The former link is just the section on double negation.)

It has this to say on the subject of double negation:

> A double negative is very often interpreted as a positive statement in English (e.g., “It is not unknown for double negatives to occur in C source”). The same semantics that apply in C. However, in some languages (e.g., Spanish) a double negative is interpreted as making the statement more negative (this usage does occur in casual English speech, e.g., “you haven’t seen nothing yet”, but it is rare and frowned on socially[1](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.3.pdf)).

I believe that the author would be happy knowing that this is of no use whatsoever in answering your real question (the answer to which is yes.)

Comment: the criteria for voting is usefulness, and this answer, as you said, 'is of no use whatsoever'.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, I respectfully disagree, as does the FAQ: *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."* Anyway, merry Christmas and happy new year.

Comment: @Tim But the arrow for upvotes says "This answer is useful". Now, your post has the correct answer to the question at the end, so one can make a case for its usefulness. But is it useful enough to upvote? Not really, considering only the part concerning the OP's question. But for research effort and a terrific find, I stretch the rules a bit ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer well thank you kindly. However I wasn't looking for up votes - it really is a comment, not an answer - I just didn't want DVs :)

Comment: I understood that, but I wanted to reward you for the funniest find in weeks :D

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm glad you enjoyed it. Too good not to share.