# Is using '!!' in C/C++ good practice and is it common?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

As far as I know, no C/C++ books tutorials or manuals mention this technique. Maybe because it's just a tiny little thing, not worth mentioning.

I use it because C/C++ mixes bool type with int, long, pointer, double etc...together. It's very common to need to convert a non-bool to bool. It's not safe to use (bool)value to do that, so I use `!!` to do it.

Example:

```
bool bValue = !!otherValue;
```

Comment: I haven't heard of any problems with it.

Comment: "It's not safe to use (bool)value to do that" Why?

Comment: This matter was already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617090/double-negation-in-c-is-it-guaranteed-to-return-0-1

Comment: There's no such language as C/C++.

Comment: @MarkByers: Yet there are concepts that apply equally well to both.  This is not one of them however...

Comment: It's pretty ugly. And generally not needed, at least not in C++.  There is an inbuilt conversion for integer to bool, T* to bool, etc.

Comment: If you don't want to use a C-style cast like `(bool)value`, then try a C++-style conversion, like `bool(value)` :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: That is still a c-style cast. C++ cast would be `static_cast<bool>(value)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `!!` is quite clear in comparison to some of the other choices such as :

```
if (foo)
  bar = 1;
else
  bar = 0;
```

or `bar = foo ? 1 : 0;`

Since `!!` does exactly one thing, I find it very unambiguous.

Comment: Well, I agree that it's ok, but `!!foo` is *less* ambiguous than `foo ? 1 : 0`?  I can't agree with that.

Comment: @EdS. Heh, in fact, I posted mainly to counter your post -- I disagreed with your point of view, and figured we'd let the votes decide. So far you're well in the lead. :)

Comment: Well, you came into the game late, so give it some time :D

Comment: I *never* use this in C++ (I cast or implicitly convert to `bool`), but I use it fairly often in C. To my eye, `!!x` is so obvious that I see a `!!` operator, not just two `!`s.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Some people do actually think that `!!` is its own operator and get confused. =/

Comment: Some people also think `-->` is its own operator... ;-)

Comment: @jamesdlin: not people with any amount of experience with the language.

Answer (score 19):

It's fine, any C or C++ programmer should recognize it, but I would prefer something more explicit like

```
(x != 0)
```

Comment: +1 Clearer code is better code

Answer (score 5):

In this exact case:

```
bool bValue = !!otherValue;
```

you don't need to write `!!`. It will work fine without them:

```
bool bValue = otherValue;
```

I think in most cases implicit casting will be nice.

Comment: Implicit casting (when it can cause data truncation) causes compiler warnings, explicit casting (via operators in this case) does not.