# Why use !!(condition) instead of (condition)?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I've seen code where people have used conditional clauses with two '!'s

```
#define check_bit(var, pos)       (!!((var) & (1 << (pos))))
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect(!!(x),1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect(!!(x),0)
```

are some of the examples I could find.

Is there any advantage in using `!!(condition)` over `(condition)`?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406063/is-using-in-c-c-good-practice-and-is-it-common), and many more...

Comment: Oh man, sorry about that!

Comment: @Siidheesh it depends how you search, my initial searches did not turn them up either but slight modifications later on did. I personally don't find any of the dups to have hit the nail on the head they way the kernel newbies thread I found does so for that nugget it was probably worth it. Also Keith's explanation is also a far better explanation than most of the others in the dups as well, but he usually writes great answers in general.

Comment: Yeah, searching for double negation did the trick

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well if the variable you are applying `!!` is not already a `bool`(*either zero or one*) then it will *normalize* the value to either `0` or `1`.

With respect to `__builtin_expect` this [kernel newbies thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/5700) discusses the notation and one of the responses explains (*emphasis mine*):

> The signature of __builtin_expect
>
> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is:
>
> long __builtin_expect (long exp, long c)
>
> Note that the exp parameter should be an integral expression, thus no pointers
>   or floating point types there. The **double negation handles the conversion from
>   these types to integral expressions automatically**. This way, **you can simply
>   write: likely(ptr) instead of likely(ptr != NULL)**.

For reference in *C99* `bool` macro expands to  `_Bool`, `true` expands to `1` and `false` expands to `0`. The details are given in the draft standard section `7.16` *Boolean type and values* .

Logical negation is covered in `6.5.3.3` *Unary arithmetic operators* in paragraph *5*:

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int.
>   The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

Answer (score 6):

The unary `!` logical negation operator, applied to any scalar, yields the `int` value `0` if its operand is non-zero, `1` if the operand is equal to zero. Quoting the standard:

> The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

Applying `!` twice to the same scalar value yields a result that's false if the value is false, true if the value is true -- but the result is normalized to `0` or `1`, respectively.

In most cases, this isn't necessary, since any scalar value can be used directly as a condition. But in some cases you actually need a `0` or `1` value.

In C99 or later, casting the expression to `_Bool` (or to `bool` if you have `#include <stdbool.h>` behaves similarly and might be considered clearer. But (a) the result is of type `_Bool` rather than `int`, and (b) if you're using a pre-C99 compiler that doesn't support `_Bool` and you've defined your own `bool` type, it won't behave the same way as C99's `_Bool`.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest I can see, is that it will force (or normalize) the value into `1` or `0` (that is a boolean value) regardless of how the `x` or `var` expression expands (e.g. `char` or `double` or `int` or etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It casts to a boolean, which can sometimes be useful.

Comment: This is C rather than C++ - there are no booleans.

Comment: Doesn't C lack a native boolean type?

Comment: There is `bool` in `C` if you include `stdbool.h`

Comment: Originally C didn't have a boolean type, so people got used to using `int` for booleans and converting integers (in `int`) to "booleans" (in `int`)

Comment: @Siidheesh `_Bool` is the native type.

Comment: @arshajii Yep, _Bool is builtin in C99, sorry :)

Comment: No, it doesn't cast it to a boolean. It "converts" it (though it's not really a conversion) to `int` with the value `0` or `1`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Yes, I know what it does. It just doesn't cast to a boolean. (Only a cast operator can "cast" something; an implicit conversion is not a cast, and this isn't even a conversion.)