# double negation to check against not NULL

Tags: c++, null, logical-operators

I have been seeing people writing code like

```
SomeType c=....

    if(!!c)
    {
     ....
    }
```

in what circumstance, would it be difference from

```
if (c)
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: When `c` isn't a `bool` (with a `true` or `false` value at least).

Comment: [Operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: so this means it is acutally same as if(c == true), which can also do the conversion of c to a bool

Comment: @chris Well, they would be the same for an `int` too.

Comment: I think it's the same as `if ((bool)c)` as well.

Comment: @BoBTFish, Yeah, I didn't pay attention to the context too much. It would differ if the numerical value was used.

Comment: If there's ever a discrepancy between those two forms, that's a sign of bad coding.

Comment: Note that this is one of the cases where an expression is "contextually converted to bool", so `if(X)` is considered the same as `if((bool)X)`. (This works even if `X` has an **`explicit`** conversion to `bool`).

Comment: @Max, As long as a conversion from `SomeType` to `bool` exists.

Comment: @KKKoo0 No, for integers `(c == true)` checks whether `(c == 1)` (the `true` is promoted to an integer, rather than `c` to being demoted to a boolean).

Comment: @chris indeed, this can be [used to normalize to 0 or 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20916491/1708801).

Comment: Before C++11, one might define `operator!` to give some kind of "validness" test, but not define `operator bool` since that could cause confusing implicit conversions to numeric types. In that case, you'd need `!!` to express "valid". (These days, `explicit operator bool` does the job nicely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This practice originates from the C language.  Before C had a boolean type.

When `c` is `0`, `!!c` is also `0`.

When `c` is **any other value**, `!!c` is always `1`.

This converts `c` into a true 2-state boolean.  Testing expressions like `( !!bool1 == !!bool2 )` or `( !!bool3 == TRUE )` will give the expected result, even if these values are different bitwise representations of "true".

Comment: Is it necessary in C++ any more?

Comment: @NeilKirk assuming `operator!` isn't overloaded to do something bizarre for the given type, it is not necessary.  It's functionally equivalent to any cast to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the following generates a warning in Microsoft Visual C++:

```
int i = GetSomeValue();
bool b = (bool) i;

warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

My intent is clear but the compiler insists on generating the warning. If I use the double negation then the warning goes away.

```
int i = GetSomeValue();
bool b = !!i;
```