# Need help understanding this logical expression !!i + !j

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [double negation in C : is it guaranteed to return 0/1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617090/double-negation-in-c-is-it-guaranteed-to-return-0-1)

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 2, j = 1;

  printf("%d", !!i +!j);
  return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, the !! turns the expression into a bool, so is it saying since i not equal to 2 the value is 0 + j which is not equal to 1 the value is 0, and since 0 is equal to false it reads: false + false = true which represents the value of 1.  Please help I am new to C programming.

Answer (score 7):

C doesn't have a boolean type (well, C99 and newer do, but there's nothing in your program that uses it).

`!` is just a unary operator that turns `0` into `1` and anything else into `0`.  So in your case, since `i` is `2`, `!i` is `0`, and `!!i` is `1`.  `j` is `1`, so `!j` is `0`.  That leaves `!!i + !j` to be be `1 + 0`, and you're printing `1`.  Try out this example program to see it in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 2, j = 1;

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    printf("!i = %d, !!i = %d\n", !i, !!i);
    printf("!j = %d\n", !j);
    printf("!!i + !j = %d + %d = %d\n", !!i, !j, !!i + !j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`!x` is 0 if `x` is true (i.e. not equal to 0) or 1 if `x` is false (i.e. equal to 0). Since your example `i` is 2, `!i` will be 0 and thus `!!i` will be 1. Likewise `!j` will be 0. So the result of the expression will be `1 + 0 = 1`.

Note that there are no circumstances under which `0 + 0` (i.e. false + false) would equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the specification states about the `!` operator (C99 §6.5.3.3/5).  The terse last sentence is all that is really required to understand its behavior:

> The result of the logical negation operator `!`is `0` if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`.
>
> The result has type `int`.
>
> The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

We can use the transformation from the third sentence to evaluate your expression, `!!i + !j`.  The transformation becomes:

```
(0 == (0 == i)) + (0 == j)
```

and we can evaluate it as follows:

```
(0 == (0 == 2)) + (0 == 1) // substitute the variable values
(0 == (0     )) + (0 == 1) // 0 == 2 is false, so it becomes 0
(0 == (0     )) + (0     ) // 0 == 1 is false, so it becomes 0
(1            ) + (0)      // 0 == 0 is true, so it becomes 1
 1                         // 1 + 0 is 1
```