# strcmp returns 1 when 2 strings are equal, Why?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have the following code. I took it from http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int
main(void)
{
  /* Hashed form of "GNU libc manual". */
  const char *const pass = "$1$/iSaq7rB$EoUw5jJPPvAPECNaaWzMK/";

  char *result;
  int ok;

  printf("%s\n",pass);

  /* Read in the user’s password and encrypt it,                                                                                                    
     passing the expected password in as the salt. */
  result = crypt(getpass("Password:"), pass);

  printf("%s\n",result); /*I added this printf*/
  /* Test the result. */
  ok = strcmp (result, pass) == 0;
  printf("valor de la comparacion: %i\n",ok);/*I added it*/
  puts(ok ? "Access granted." : "Access denied.");
  return ok ? 0 : 1;
}
```

When I type GNU libc manual the output is "Acces granted". but the value returned by strcmp is 1  and this value means that result and pass are not equal. However the output is :

```
$1$/iSaq7rB$EoUw5jJPPvAPECNaaWzMK/
Password:
$1$/iSaq7rB$EoUw5jJPPvAPECNaaWzMK/
valor de la comparacion: 1
Access granted.
```

I am very confused about behavior of strcmp.

Comment: I think is checking condition `strcmp (result, pass) == 0` as this condition is true thats why it is returning `1`. Try to print `strcmp (result, pass)` in `printf`.

Comment: I would expect strcmp (result, pass) == 0 to return a non-zero number if the two strings had the same content.

Comment: @bvj if two strings have same content it will return 0.

Comment: @Himanshu "It" being strcmp, correct. So then to my point, how would 0==0 evaluate?

Comment: @bvj `0==0` means condition is true(as zero is equal to zero), so it will return `1`.

Comment: @Himanshu The expression 0==0 may produce 1, or some other non-zero value.

Comment: @bvj: are you sure? I think that it's guaranteed to be 1 in C, but I don't have my C book handy. Any non-zero value would evaluate as true, of course.

Comment: @yellowantphil In my experience, optimization reliably yields true values other than 1 (excluding 0 of course.)

Comment: @bvj Interesting, thanks. Maybe I just assumed that it was always 1. I'll try some optimized code and look into it some more sometime.

Comment: @bvj The C standard requires the return value of `==` to be either 0 or 1: [What is !0 in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661751/what-is-0-in-c). Maybe your optimizer thinks that it can get away with violating the standard, in the situations you've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the value of `ok`.

On this line:

```
ok = strcmp (result, pass) == 0;
```

it compares the return value of `strcmp` to `0`. They are equal, so the comparison is true. That sets `ok` to `1`. Setting an integer to the result of a boolean comparison gives `1` for true, and `0` for false.

Comment: and small rectification is -- remove `== 0` :)

Comment: that's right. I am wrong ok it's the value of strcmp(result,pass) == 0. it is not the value returned by strcmp itself

Comment: And as remyabel just pointed out, that line of code depends on `=` having a lower operator precedence than `==`.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` has lower precedence than the relational operator `==`. So the statement `ok = strcmp (result, pass) == 0;` is equivalent to `ok = (strcmp (result, pass) == 0);`. You are **not** assigning the result of `strcmp` to `ok`, but the result of `strcmp (result, pass) == 0`.