# Why is my code skipping a whole for loop?

Tags: c

I'm still learning the basics of C and I had this assignment of coding a program that shows the product of two 2D arrays entered by the user. The idea is to not make use of memory functions like malloc.

The code worked fine but when I added an if statement to check that the rows of the first array are equal to the columns of the next one during the run-time the whole part for entering the data of the first array and showing it is skipped and it goes directly to asking for the next array. I've tried to clean the buffer and use getch() trying to force the compiler to execute that part but it keeps being skipped.

Here's the whole code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void);
int main (void)
#define MAXR 36
#define MAXC 18 
{
    int Rows_A,Columns_A,Rows_B,Columns_B,Rows_C,Columns_C;
int Counter_Rows=0,Counter_Columns=0,Counter_Multiplier=0;
int Matrix_A[MAXR][MAXC],Matrix_B[MAXR][MAXC],Results_Matrix_C[MAXR][MAXC];
printf("\n\tTo multiply two matrices both have to be the same size of rows from the first matrix and the columns from the next one. \n\tPlease enter the size of the matrices:\n");

printf("\n\tMatrix A:\n\tNumber of rows :\t\t");
scanf(" %d",&Rows_A);
printf("\n\tNumber of columns :\t\t");
scanf(" %d",&Columns_A);
printf("\n\tMatrix B:\n\tNumber of rows :\t\t");
fflush(stdin);
scanf(" %d",&Rows_B);
printf("\n\tNumber of columns :\t\t");
scanf(" %d",&Columns_B);
if (Rows_A=!Columns_B)
{
    printf("\n\tMatrix B number of columns and Matrix A number of rows are not the same therefore they cannot be multiplied.");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    Rows_C=Rows_A;
    Columns_C=Columns_B;
    printf("\n\tEnter the data for Matrix A:");
    for (Counter_Rows=0;Counter_Rows < Rows_A;Counter_Rows++)
    {   
        for(Counter_Columns=0;Counter_Columns < Columns_A; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter the value of the position [%d][%d] of the matrix A:  ",Counter_Rows+1,Counter_Columns+1);
            scanf(" %d",&Matrix_A[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tMatrix A.\n\t");//Matrix A
    for (Counter_Rows= 0; Counter_Rows < Rows_A; Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for (Counter_Columns= 0; Counter_Columns < Columns_A; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("[%d] ",Matrix_A[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
        printf("\n\t");
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\tEnter the data for Matrix B:");
    for (Counter_Rows=0;Counter_Rows < Rows_B;Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for(Counter_Columns=0;Counter_Columns < Columns_B; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter the value of the position [%d][%d] of the matrix B:  ",Counter_Rows+1,Counter_Columns+1);
            scanf(" %d",&Matrix_B[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tMatrix B.\n\t");//Matrix B.
    for (Counter_Rows= 0; Counter_Rows < Rows_B; Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for (Counter_Columns= 0; Counter_Columns < Columns_B; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("[%d] ",Matrix_B[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
        printf("\n\t");
    }
    //Calculating product matrix C.
    for (Counter_Rows=0;Counter_Rows < Rows_C;Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for(Counter_Columns=0;Counter_Columns < Columns_C; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            //initializes the Matrix  C in 0's
            Results_Matrix_C[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]=0;
            for(Counter_Multiplier=0; Counter_Multiplier < Columns_A; Counter_Multiplier++)
            {
                Results_Matrix_C[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]=Results_Matrix_C[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]+(Matrix_A[Counter_Rows][Counter_Multiplier]*Matrix_B[Counter_Multiplier][Counter_Columns]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tProduct Matrix C:\n\t");//Matrix B.
    for (Counter_Rows= 0; Counter_Rows < Rows_C; Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for (Counter_Columns= 0; Counter_Columns < Columns_C; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("[%d] ",Results_Matrix_C[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
        printf("\n\t");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

This is the part that is skipped :

```
printf("\n\tEnter the data for Matrix A:");
    for (Counter_Rows=0;Counter_Rows < Rows_A;Counter_Rows++)
    {   
        for(Counter_Columns=0;Counter_Columns < Columns_A; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter the value of the position [%d][%d] of the matrix A:  ",Counter_Rows+1,Counter_Columns+1);
            scanf(" %d",&Matrix_A[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tMatrix A.\n\t");//Matrix A
    for (Counter_Rows= 0; Counter_Rows < Rows_A; Counter_Rows++)
    {
        for (Counter_Columns= 0; Counter_Columns < Columns_A; Counter_Columns++)
        {
            printf("[%d] ",Matrix_A[Counter_Rows][Counter_Columns]);
        }
        printf("\n\t");
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please, emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: also, debugging would get out out of this exact situation. You should take the time to learn how to debug. You will save countless hours and frustration later.

Comment: Time to learn some basic debugging. Attempting to program without any recourse to debugging is not productive. It's like driving a car with your eyes closed.

Comment: Also, `#define` in the middle of your `main` function stub, really? also, make a **minimal** example.

Comment: Is `if (Rows_A=!Columns_B)` true or false? Oh, wait... now I see it. Change that to `!=`.

Comment: `rowsA=!columsB` are you sure it's `equal not`, and not, `not equals`, which would be `!=`?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Marc B shouldn't any reasonable compiler warn here... testing this... stand by..

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would hope so, but I know how a lot of developers treat warnings. :(

Comment: @BilltheLizard: gcc 4.9 only does so with `-Wall`: `t.c:5:2: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  if(a=!b)
`

Comment: NOTting a signed integer should result in something, surely?  Anyway, it would have taken me ages to spot that error by just looking at the code - I'm not that good:)

Comment: @MartinJames: don't beat yourself up over that, OP's code is horribly formatted and not cleaned up at all...

Comment: No warning about `if (Rows_A=!Columns_B)` from MSVC although (in other circs) it warns about precedence and possibly missing brackets.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which is the same as the gcc warning.

Comment: What happened to your debugger?

Comment: @WeatherVane clang says `t.c:5:6: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        if(a=!b)
           ~^~~
t.c:5:6: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
        if(a=!b)
            ^
           (   )
t.c:5:6: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
        if(a=!b)
            ^
            ==
1 warning generated.
`

Comment: This is why I love C, (not:).  Once every decade, somewhere in the world, some dev. really wants to NOT a signed integer.  All the other times, it's a bug.  So. no warning then:(

Comment: @BilltheLizard: to little surprise, clang had the highest quality of warning, and the highest default level of alarm :)

Comment: @MartinJames it's reasonably common.. especially in C89 (where there is no true boolean), a signed integer type is used for boolean values.  Another use is after testing flags, e.g. `if ( !(flags & 0x400) )`

Comment: Sorry for the long variables but my teacher is REALLY strict with the names of everything in the code.

Comment: @MartinJames that's a logical !not as opposed to to a bitwise ~not. Perfectly OK in C with int, anything non-0 is true.

Comment: @Daniekiske oh, don't apologise for that!  The times I've moaned about single-letter var names on SO...

Comment: @WeatherVane meh..  OK...   ish.. :)

Comment: Nobody said this explicitly yet, but `if (Rows_A=!Columns_B)` causes `Rows_A = 0` to happen , so then then the loop with condition `Counter_Rows < Rows_A` never has its body entered, because `0 < 0` is false.  OP thinks the loop was "skipped" when in fact it completed immediately .  Also the line `printf("\n\tEnter the data for Matrix A:");` should have been printed, I guess that was just bad reporting by OP saying it was skipped.

Comment: @Daniekiske really clean up your code, though. Otherwise, with the next vote, this question will be closed due to you not giving a **minimal** example.

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard.

Comment: Also, note @stackptr comment.  It would have taken me a long time to find this bug by just looking.  With a debugger, however...

Comment: Note that declaring `int main();` is non-standard and might even hide errors.

Answer (score 2):

you have `if (Rows_A=!Columns_B)` in your example.  I think you want `if (Rows_A != Columns_B)`

Comment: So then, explain the difference.

Comment: `Rows_A=!Columns_B` becomes `(Rows_a = !Columns_b) != 0`.

Comment: yeah thanks,  I changed that and also the #define misplacing i'm noob still .

Comment: @stackptr Maybe you misunderstood me. I justed wanted that grambo25 explains it a little better.

Comment: The thing to understand about this is that, assuming `Columns_B` is non-zero, it will set `Rows_A` to zero.  And that explains why some of the loops are not being executed.

Comment: @Tom Karzes and that is caused by using =! ? I changed that to != and it worked but I still don't understand it very well.

Comment: Here is a different post explaining that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661751/what-is-0-in-c

It says in one of the comments, "This behavior of the ! operator was mentioned in K&R first edition in section 2.6 on page 38: 'The unary negation operator ! converts a non-zero or true operand into 0, and a zero of false operand into 1.' – RBerteig Sep 7 '10 at 22:19"

Comment: @Daniekiske If you write `a != b`, that is a comparison (which is what you wanted).  The `!=` operator is a single token in that case.  But if you write `a =! b`, then `=!` is two tokens, `=` and `!`.  Changing the spacing for clarity, you have `a = !b`.  In other words, you are assigning the value `!b` to `a`.  The `!` operator is logical negation, so as long as `b` is non-zero, `!b` will be zero.  In that case, it is equivalent to `a = 0`.  The value of the assignment expression is `0`, and `a` also now has the value `0`.

Comment: @Tom Karzes thank you very much now I see why.