# What ! do when initializing a variable before the value

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I was doing some random stuff and I came up with `int a = !3;` and when I outputted the value it I was expecting an error but it got me a **0**.

Why did this happen and what **!** means on that example?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661859/2201041)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is the `BOOLEAN NOT` operator, i.e. `!true == false` and `!false == true`. In C and C++ every value that is nonzero is treated as `true` when used with a boolean operator. And `false` is numerically `0`. So `3` is treated as `true` and `!3 = !true = false = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

!3 is an expression, it evaluates to a bool type.
In this example it evaluates to false.

bool's can be casted to an int, which happens automatically when you assign it to one.
The int representation of false is '0' whilst true is '1'.

Answer (score 0):

That "negates" the value. Anything non-zero becomes `0`, and `0` becomes `1`.

Comment: `-` negates the value.  `!` negates the truthiness.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's why I used the quotes. It's boolean negation, but not binary negation (`~`) or mathematical negation (`-`).